# I need more corpses

Tags: dead-space-3

I've noticed in Dead Space 3 that on some occasions corpses from Necromorphs seem to disappear entirely too quickly. It seems around 3 is the magic number, though I've had some disappear before my eyes leaving only a single corpse in the area. Since I need to "check" corpses for items by viciously stomping them, corpses disappearing means A) I have to check them in combat (not pleasant on Hard) and I miss some items (also not cool).

Is there some settings tweak (.ini? Config file?) that will let me stack up the bodies? I have a high end gaming PC and graphics are maxed, so my system can handle much more rotting flesh than I'm currently getting.

Comment: Normally I just make sure when I finish them I impale them with their spike to knock the loot out of them. Takes no time at all and ensures you never miss a body.

Comment: @Emerica. not sure if it's just my control set up or the Kinesis module's tendency to not grab spikes, but I find it much trickier to grab a spike and impale than in previous games so stomping is almost always easier.

Comment: Thats weird, maybe its a PC thing. I find as long as they're dead and they still have a spike remaining I am 100% gaurenteed to get the spike when I use it on their body.

Comment: @Emerica. wonder if that's a result of console auto-aim?  It seems to kinda-try to pick up spikes, but not nearly as reliably as DS2 on PS3

Comment: Likely, most games even when disabled have a form of aiming auto-assist on consoles to make up for the lack of mouse. Well if you can't just rip them off on the fly I guess you're right... MORE CORPSES!

Comment: Are you competing for the sickiest title ? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a fix for this "problem".

There are several discussions around talking about this issue if you want something to read:

- [Steam Forum 1](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3083900)
- [Steam Forum 2](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3073445)
- [Steam Forum 3](http://steamcommunity.com/app/47780/discussions/0/864960353876373658/)
- [Game FAQs 1](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975302-dead-space-2/57963744)
- [Game FAQs 2](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975302-dead-space-2/57978874)
- [Dead Space Wiki](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:44679)

An explanation for this problem could be the fact that Dead Space 3 was simply ported to PC without being optimized at all. There is an article on this topic that I recommend you read: [Dead Space 3 on PC is an unoptimized console port](http://www.geek.com/games/dead-space-3-on-pc-is-an-unoptimized-console-port-1537849/). A quote from this article:

> Steve Papoutsis, executive producer on Dead Space 3, has confirmed that the PC version of the game is just a console port. It will not be optimized for the platform.

There is similar article [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Dead-Space-3-micro-transaction-co-op-directx-11-console-port,20650.html) about the optimization of Dead Space 3.

The lack of optimization is most likely the cause of this issue, and also explains why console players don't experience the same problem.